# What is the consequence of running a 2nd commit in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

While using a MySQL transaction, is there a problem if you `commit` twice? e.g.

```
START TRANSACTION
/* Various DB UPDATEs */
COMMIT
COMMIT
```

Having tested it out, it seems the 2nd COMMIT is a NO OP and could equally be a `ROLLBACK`, is that correct? Is it harmless or could it ever be a problem?

As I understand it, after the 1st commit, auto-commit would be enabled and so the 2nd commit is meaningless... But would it cause any harm?

---

Background info:

I'm using PHP and I have a database transaction, e.g.

```
$dbconnection->getPdoInstance()->beginTransaction();
/* ... Various DB UPDATEs */
$dbconnection->getPdoInstance()->commit();
```

However, I want to put a [MYSQL COMMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comments.html)  on my commit so that I can identify it when I see it in the `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, therefore I can't use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php), I have to use "raw" SQL:

```
$dbconnection->getPdoInstance()->beginTransaction();
/* ... various DB UPDATEs */
$dbconnection->createCommand("COMMIT /* My Comment */")->execute();
```

Except this doesn't work because as far as PDO is concerned the transaction would still be active so it would throw an exception on the next `beginTransaction()`, e.g.

> *exception 'PDOException' with message 'There is already an active transaction'*

One workaround would be this:

```
$dbconnection->getPdoInstance()->beginTransaction();
/* ... various DB UPDATEs */
$dbconnection->createCommand("COMMIT /* My Comment */")->execute();
$dbconnection->getPdoInstance()->commit();
```

which would mean two `COMMITs` are done, the first with my comment, the 2nd as a no-op but would close the transaction for pdo. (hence the question).

Another workaround would be to leave pdo out altogether:

```
$dbconnection->createCommand("START TRANSACTION")->execute();
/* ... various DB UPDATEs */
$dbconnection->createCommand("COMMIT /* My Comment */")->execute();
```

But then you lose the pdo features such as [intransaction()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.intransaction.php) and you won't get an exception if you try to start a 2nd transaction while already inside a prior transaction.

Comment: Is the commit taking the most time or why do you want exactly the commit command to have your comment? You could use any no-op command, like "select 1;".

Comment: Yes, the commit is taking a long time and showing in the mysql slow-log. This is why I wanted to comment it, so I can then have the info to link the commit with the action that caused it.

Answer (score 1):

On Mysql, two commits are not a problem.

On PDO, im not sure. What if you change the first commit to another command like:

```
$dbconnection->getPdoInstance()->beginTransaction();
/* ... various DB UPDATEs */
$dbconnection->createCommand("SET @dummy_var=1; /* My Comment */")->execute();
$dbconnection->getPdoInstance()->commit();
```

Comment: In my app, the `COMMIT` is sometimes taking a long time, so I specifically wanted to add a comment on it so I can identify which of the many commits in our code is causing the slow-down. I'm still trying to figure out why a commit would be slow: http://serverfault.com/questions/550004.